# Scala getting the concrete type of a self-type

Tags: scala, types, self-type

I'd like to get a reference to the concrete type of a self-type annotation in Scala within the self-typed trait. I have something like this:

```
trait Foo
class FooImpl1 extends Foo
class FooImpl2 extends Foo

trait SpecialFoo {
  this:Foo =>

  def |+|(that:this.type):this.type // the type signature is incorrect here
}
```

where if I do `new FooImpl1 with SpecialFoo`, I'd like the `|+|` method to require and return a `FooImpl1` (or a subtype of `FooImpl1`). However, with the above code it seems to want a `SpecialFoo.this.type`, which is unsurprising, but not what I want.

Comment: BTW shadowing `this` is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

`this.type` is the singleton type of whatever instance of `SpecialFoo` you have. As defined, `|+|` would only be able to be called with itself. For example:

```
trait Spec { def |+|(that: this.type): this.type = that }
val s = new Spec {}
val s2 = new Spec {}

scala> s |+| s
res1: <refinement>.type = $anon$1@118102ee

scala> s |+| s2
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Spec
 required: <refinement>.type
       s |+| s2
             ^
```

`this.type` *is* `FooImpl1` in some cases, but the compiler has no way of knowing that. You need some way to capture the more refined type of `FooImpl1` or `FooImpl2`. The self-type `this: Foo =>` only cares that it's a `Foo`. There are a couple possibilities, but neither will look as nice as you want.

You can parameterize `SpecialFoo`:

```
trait Foo
class FooImpl1 extends Foo
class FooImpl2 extends Foo

trait SpecialFoo[A <: Foo] { self: A =>
  def |+|(that: A): A
}

val foo = new FooImpl1 with SpecialFoo[FooImpl1] {
  def |+|(that: FooImpl1): FooImpl1 = that
}
```

Unforunately, you need to write `FooImpl1` twice, but the self-type still prevents you from mixing two different implementations.

The alternative is to use type members within `Foo`. You wouldn't have to specify the implementation type twice when creating a `SpecialFoo`, but would when creating the implementations themselves to bind the correct types.

```
trait Foo { type S }
class FooImpl1 extends Foo { type S = FooImpl1 }
class FooImpl2 extends Foo { type S = FooImpl2 }

trait SpecialFoo { self: Foo =>
  def |+|(that: self.S): self.S
}

val foo = new FooImpl1 with SpecialFoo {
  def |+|(that: FooImpl1): FooImpl1 = that
}
```

You could also make `Foo` F-bounded, i.e. `trait Foo[A <: Foo]`, and do something similar to the above example.