# How to get the type of the implementing class while writing the trait

Tags: scala, types, scala-3

**Note:***This is about Scala 3*.

Suppose I want to write a trait for classes which contain a function taking something of type A and return an object of its own type (like a set). The default implementation of the trait `Set[A]` from [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L21) looks like it is fine with the operation `incl` returning a `Set[A]` (so can be any type implementing `Set[A]`, doesn't need to be itself). Here is my attempt at writing such a thing:

```scala
trait Set[A] { self =>
    type T = self.type
    def incl(x : A) : T
}
```

This however does not work as intended, as was also observed in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451364/scala-getting-the-concrete-type-of-a-self-type), because `self.type` is the singleton type inhabited only by the object. I wonder if the new features of Scala 3 allow me to do something like this cleanly, as opposed to the solutions presented in that question.

Comment: No, also that wouldn't make sense. Say even this works, you then mix several traits like A,B,C,D. What's your expected self type? Obviously in Set trait, you'll have no idea you are mixed with all the other traits at the implementation site. If you just want to get a type of Set, I recomnend just to declare a type member and set it explicitly to Set. Or leave it unimplemented and implemented in the final class

Comment: Yeah I guess subtyping and mixing causes issues with how well-defined this is. I found a somewhat satisfactory solution with F-bounded types, so I am going with that for now.

Comment: This is FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type and no, the best way is still a typeclass. This is because there is no way to abstract over constructors.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I think typeclasses do make much more sense here. I will switch. Thanks for the help!